# What is # in XAML StringFormat?

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-stringformat-property/).  The example contains the line

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=wnd, Path=ActualWidth, StringFormat=Window width: {0:#,#.0}}" />
```

binding the window width to the textblock.  If I remove "#,#", I notice I get the same result except there is no comma in the number if it's greater than 999.  I see what it's doing.  If I change it to

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=wnd, Path=ActualWidth, StringFormat=Window width: {0:##,#.0}}" />
```

I get the same thing.  So my question is what does # mean exactly.  Looked at MSDN and searched google but almost every example does not use any # signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` is a digit placeholder numeric format specifier in .NET that is replaced with the corresponding digit if one is present. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) for more information.

It has nothing to do with XAML really. You might as well use it programmatically when you for example call the `ToString` overload of a numeric type that accepts a format string.

Comment: Missed that page.  Thanks